# How can I get length of axis' major ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, axes

I know that I can set length of ticks with `length` parameter of `AxesSubplot.tick_params()` method.

How may I determine the actual length of major ticks of certain axis?

Please assume the length may be altered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default length of the ticks is determined by the `xtick.major.size` or `ytick.major.size`, or the `xtick.minor.size` or `ytick.minor.size` rcParams.

You may find out programmatically via

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(plt.rcParams["xtick.major.size"])
```

This prints in the usual case `3.5` (size in points).

You may equally use those the rcParams to *set* the length

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["xtick.major.size"] = 6
```

This will work in all cases where you create the axes yourself and have not (yet) changed the length e.g. via the `tick_params` method.

Otherwise, you can find out the tick length via

```
ax.xaxis.majorTicks[0].tick1line.get_markersize()
```

where `ax` is the axes in question.